# Container of int *not Integer* type in Java

Tags: java, integer, int, containers

I need to have a container for a couple of integers that I'm writing on a file, but it has to be of type `int` instead of `Integer` for the sake of minimum bytes taken (32 bits). I know that both `Arraylists` and `Vectors` won't take an int so is there a way to do that?

Comment: What wrong with just a plain array?

Comment: @August I'm not supposed to use that in my program.

Comment: Part of your question is confusing.  If you are writing these integers to file, what difference does it make if they are of type int or Integer while in memory?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are talking about. Whether you use `int` or `Integer` has no bearing on whatever you are writing to your file. If you can write an `int` properly then you can write an `Integer` properly and vice versa (the difference in syntax is also made negligible than it already is by auto [un]boxing). Both hold a signed 32-bit integer and so their value ranges are the same as well. You need to show your relevant code, how you are using these, and what problems you have run into with `Integer` - either that or be clearer with your intention and requirements.

Comment: @JasonC I didn't know that `int` and `integer` take the same memory. How is that?

Comment: @dili Why are you concerned with the amount of memory they take? Both represent the same thing. Put a minimal amount of effort into [reading the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) first.

Comment: @JasonC What do you mean why I care? I'm writing a huffman encoding program and I need to convert the binary `String` result into an integer for minimum compression size. That's the whole point of my question actually. And I did read about it before asking. But found nothing useful.

Comment: We're confused about where you need "minimum bytes taken".  When you write to a file, you can write an integer in as many bytes as you want - 1, 2, 4, 6, 27.  You just need enough bytes to represent the number, *and* you need to somehow know how many bytes the number occupies when you read it.

Comment: A Huffman coding scheme writes a variable number of bits for each number, based on the code.  Has nothing to do with arrays or "containers" or whatever.  Generally you will work on one byte or 32-bit int at a time, fill that up, write it out, then fill another.

Comment: (It sounds like you've got yourself barking up the wrong tree.  Go back and study Huffman coding some more.  Look at several different examples on the web.  Then forget what you've been trying and try something fresh.)

Comment: @HotLicks Exactly! I have a file of let's say 20 lines. Ill need more than 40 ints to represent it. And a container that holds these numbers will much help me in displaying on a Swing JtextArea. That's all.

Comment: @dili So use an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: You're not making sense.  How does a Swing JtextArea have anything to do with Huffman coding?

Comment: @HotLicks Nothing at all. I said I'm displaying on it, and having my ints previously arranged in some data type will **help** me alot in that. I'm displaying on it as well as writing on file. Not related.

Comment: @dili You need to describe the actual problem you're having with `Integer` and why it has not worked out for you.

Comment: @JasonC I thought int (primitive type) and Integer (an object) take different space in memory. I need to use an int space (i.e. 32 bits)

Comment: It sounds to me like you're confusing the amount of RAM that something will take with the amount of bits that it can usefully hold. An Integer will absolutely take more RAM than an int, but it'll still only give you 32 bits of information (not counting whether it's null). When you transfer that information to a file, or `byte[]`, or network buffer, or anything else -- it doesn't matter how much RAM it took, all that matters is that it only has 32 bits of information. An `Integer` is nothing more than a simple class with one field, an `int value`.

Comment: @dili They do take different amounts of memory, and again I ask: Why does it matter? **The amount of memory required to store these objects in RAM has absolutely no relation to however you choose to store a 32-bit value in a file.** So you need to **tell us why `Integer` is not working for you, specifically** or otherwise clarify your question. See also [XY Problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @dili If that's all you needed to know then you did not actually read the documentation I linked to, which states that an `Integer` is a simple class with one `int` field virtually in the first sentence. You've wasted all of our time by being unclear and refusing to do a minimal amount of research on your own.

Comment: @JasonC I did read it and searched the web too :) I'm just **too new to this** and have no idea what the fact of *class with one int* would help me with nor how RAM is different from actual bit representaion :) And I thought this site was made for learning that's why I asked. My bad.

Comment: @dili This site is *not* for tutoring. This site is for helping with specific problems with clear problem statements after you have tried something on your own and have a concrete issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. A valid question on this site would be, "I am trying to do X. When I use `Integer` instead of `int` I have ABC problems. I have tried Y to solve it to no avail. How can I approach this problem?" From your question, it appears you have tried nothing.

Comment: @JasonC I have writen the whole program I promise :) But why would I be posting a System.out statements? It runs perfecty but I needed to enhance it for not using int arrays **as was required in the assignment for another reason** :) But you're right, I might have not been able to describe my problem more clearly cuz I thought it was clear enough. and sorry again for wasting **your** time.

Comment: You haven't told us where/how you're using the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing for "minimum compression size," it doesn't matter how much memory your data takes up when the program's operating over it: only how much memory it takes when you write out the compressed file.  It's perfectly fine to use boxed `Integer`s to manipulate the data initially; you just have to convert when you're writing the file.

Comment: You don't even have to manually convert. I can't imagine any such `int`-based code that would require any changes to work with `Integer` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use a **int array**, for storing primitive int type data.

*Containers mean objects*, that wrap the primitive data and provide additional functionality. Thus container instances would be larger than 32 bits for any wrapped int data.

Answer (score 1):

There are collection libraries that support storing primitive values, but they are not part of the standard Java library.

- [PCJ](http://pcj.sourceforge.net/)
- [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/)
- [HPPC](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/hppc.html)

Generally, you would only need one of these for specific performance or memory requirements. If you haven't even written your program, then you probably aren't in need of them.

You could also use an [IntBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html), but that won't give you a collection-like interface. Instead this is essentially a lightweight wrapper around a byte buffer (or primitive byte array) and is mostly used for reading and writing to and from files, network sockets, or interacting with native code.

Comment: Suggesting PCJ in 2014?

Comment: @leventov It wasn't so much a recommendation as an example that this problem has been solved and for quite some time. If you've got better examples feel free to chime in.

Answer (score 0):

if you'r not supposed to use a simple int[] you simply "cannot" do that in an easy way..

the int is a primitive not an object (as Integer)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class IntContaner {
    public int intOne;
    public int intTwo;
}
```

(But, of course, anything you use will take more than 2x32 bits.)

Comment: This could be it. But I can't know the number of ints for sure. It varies according to input.

Comment: @dili - So why not an array?

Comment: It's an assignment. I shouldn't be using arrays in the answer. But since there can't be a way I have to rethink the whole thing I guess.